# $_FILES array but only first file uploads

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload multiple image files.  If the image name is "icon.jpg" then it's moved to a different place than any other images - this seems to be working ok however only the first image is uploaded and moved.

The script stops after the first image and says "Query was empty" even though I'm trying to upload at least 4 or 5 other images.

```
$id = '01';
foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $n => $image) 
if(!empty($image)) {
{
 if ($image == 'icon.jpg'){
  $target_path = "../images/articles/".$id."_small.jpg";
  } else {
  $target_path = "../images/galleries/".$id."/pk_hb" . $id.".jpg";
  }
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$n], $target_path);
$id++;
 }
}
```

I've included the dynamic JS upload form I'm using, in case this is the problem:

```
<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="add">
Image 1: <input name='file[]' type='file' accept="image/*" />
<div id='file_tools'>
    <img src='../images/top/file_add.png' id='add_file' title='Add new input'/>
    <img src='../images/top/file_del.png' id='del_file' title='Delete'/>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 2;
$('#del_file').hide();
$('img#add_file').click(function(){
    $('#file_tools').before('Image '+counter+': <input name="file[]" type="file" accept="image/*" />');
    $('#del_file').fadeIn(0);
counter++;
});
$('img#del_file').click(function(){
    if(counter==3){
        $('#del_file').hide();
    }   
    counter--;
    $('#f'+counter).remove();
});
});
</script>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="add" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Added contents of var_dump($_FILES)

```
array(1) { 
["file"]=> array(5) 
{ 
 ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "cooley1.jpg" } 
 ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } 
 ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(18) "/var/tmp/phpLYaj7U" } 
 ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } 
 ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(106241) } 
} 
}
```

Comment: NITPICK: use label elements.

Comment: Did you do a `var_dump()` on `$_FILES`?

Comment: bug: first file will be `01.jpg`, then `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`, etc... you need to use `sprintf('%02d', $id)` to do your zero-padding. have you been checking the return value of the move command? did you check the `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for each image to make sure it did actually upload?

Comment: I've added the contents of var_dump($_FILES) - Tried to upload 5 images but only 1 is in the array

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

Unlike `$_POST`, you cannot send array of files to `$_FILES` by setting the `name` of all `input` to `file[]`. The `$_FILES` automatically contains all file you uploaded in an array :) which the key is the `name` of the file `input` element.

You have to change the name of each file `input` to `file_1`, `file_2`, ... `file_n` to make the script understand that you have multiple file to be uploaded.

You also have to check the `max-file-uploads` of you `php.ini` have the valid value http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads .

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I've edited the JS so that each input will be `file_1`, `file_2`... etc but then what do I change `file` attribute to in `foreach($_FILES['file']['name']` if it's now `file_1`, `file_2` etc?

Comment: you change to `foreach($_FILES as $fieldName => $obj)` `$fieldName` will contains the name of your `input` element (`file_1`, `file_2`, ...) and the `obj` will be an array with `name`, `type`, `tmp_name` ...

Comment: I've changed the `foreach` as you said but am still getting `Query was empty` after the first image. var_dump: `array(1) { ["file_1"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(8) "icon.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(18) "/var/tmp/phpLYaj7U" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(12296) } }`
`

Comment: I have updated the answer, try checking your `php.ini` setting.

Comment: `max_file_uploads` is 20 and `upload_max_filesize` is 3M so all should be fine there - The images are all under 150Kb

Comment: Humm, I have no idea now, try to check your input form again: every file `input` have its distinct name and belongs to the form. I have run this script locally and get all my uploaded files :(.